# How to have just author, title and year in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using biblatex with `alphabet` style. I want `\printbibliography` to only print the `author`, `title`, `date` (and possibly `doi`) fields. Is there a style for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a new driver with the stripped back output

```
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
      {\printfield{doi}}
      {}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

In order to apply this to all entry types, we use list processing

```
\def\do#1{
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
      {\printfield{doi}}
      {}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}}
\makeatletter
\abx@dotypes
\makeatother
```

Here `\abx@dotypes` executes `\do` for every known entry type. (In the upcoming version 3.4 `\abx@dotypes` will be called `\abx@doentrytypes`.)

Needless to say that this style needs to be applied with lots of care. It might be OK for books or articles with a DOI, but it can be hard to track down an article or entry in a collection without knowledge of the containing work (especially if you don't have access to the internet and in-book/in-journal search).

Comment: We should have a simple way to do that...But it works

Comment: @Vitor Such a style seems to be sufficiently unusual that no-one has bothered to implement it yet as a custom style. It is certainly no style I have ever seen out there in the wild. (Especially in the olden days before you could just google things the information given in this style could be insufficient to properly find a work. I still see this problem for `@article`s.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I currently have is by calling `\clearfield`, `\clearlist` and `\clearname` for everything I find in my `.bbl` file except `author`, `title`, `year`, and `doi`.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{journal}%
  .
  .
  .
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
```